# Kafka ConsumerGroup does not exist

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Setting up Kafka first time, Kafka 0.11. Using pretty much default configurations. Produced produced some messages to topic ABC. 2 Consumers are coded to consume messages from the same topic. Each consumer belongs to different group id GROUP.1 and GROUP.2

Want to look into the topic for all the messages and also the offset details.

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group GROUP.1
```

throws following error,

> Error: The consumer group 'GROUP.1' does not exist.

Same error for GROUP.2 also. I got some output without error for one of the group yesterday, but not today. What I'm I missing? Need to configure somewhere to persist consumer group details, or will the command work only when the consumers with given group id is currently running, or?

I tried `kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group GROUP.1` but got the same error.

Also tried Kafka-consumer-offset-checker command.

```
kafka-consumer-offset-checker --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic ABC  --group GROUP.1
```

> [2017-12-19 19:25:01,654] WARN WARNING: ConsumerOffsetChecker is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0. Use ConsumerGroupCommand instead. (kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker$)
>   Exiting due to: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/GROUP.1/offsets/ABC/2.

Comment: could you provide more details, for example, your producer and consumer code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said you saw the group details yesterday, it's probably worth noting that by default offsets are only stored for 24 hours. So if you group has not committed offsets in 24 hours, Kafka has no more information about it.

If this is indeed the issue, you can increase the time by setting `offsets.retention.minutes` to a larger value.

Comment: Ahh yes this should  be it.

Comment: Its like whole ConsumerGroup details are expired, not just Offset. So the property names  - offsets.retention.* are kind of misleading, isn't it?

Comment: ^ same in here. My consumer group was completely "wiped out" any history of it as well